# Counting files in folder without wc

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

Why does the following scripts give a count of 0 instead of giving the count of files present in the directory?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /root/Jamshed/script
count=0
ls -lrt > all_files
cat all_files | while read dir
do  
    count=$(($count + 1))
done
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 6):

It is giving the `count` as zero because you are increment `count` within a subshell.  As such, the *changes* made to the variable are *lost*.

Instead say:

```
while read -r dir
do  
    count=$(($count + 1))
done < all_files
```

to achieve the desired result.

That said, [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is never recommended.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an array to hold the filenames and examine the array size:

```
files=( /root/Jamshed/script/* )
echo "${#files[@]}"
```

If you want all files recursively:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
files=( /root/Jamshed/script/** )
echo "${#files[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without parsing `ls` output or using `wc` as follows:

```
cd /root/Jamshed/script
count=0
shopt -s nullglob
for file in * .*[!.]*;do
    count=$(($count+1))
done
echo $count
```

**Explanation**

The glob pattern `*` will match all file and directory names not starting with a `.` and the glob pattern `.*[!.]*`  will match all file and directory names whose name starts with a `.` and contains at least one non-`.` character (to avoid counting the special directories `.` and `..`).

Comment: That would avoid counting `...` and `.....` as well. Note that the standard syntax is `[!.]`, not `[^.]`. Note that in an empty directory, it would return 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your script works fine in ksh, you can also change the first line (on Linux the ksh package must have been installed).
`#!/bin/ksh`
ksh doen not use subshells in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `bash` [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) you may - from `bash 4.2` on - use `shopt -s lastpipe` to avoid the subshell issue (variable assignment in child process is not visible in the parent shell).

(Yet another way to avoid the subshell issue is to use `exec` and redirect stdin from a file or heredoc).

If you insist on using `ls`, use `ls -1Artb`.

```
# file version
set +f
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
count=0
printf '%s\000' * > all_files
while IFS="" read -r -d "" file; do
   test -z "$file" && continue
   count=$(($count + 1))
   #printf '%s\n' "$count: $file"
done < all_files
echo "$count"

# process substitution version
set +f
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
count=0
while IFS="" read -r -d "" file; do
   test -z "$file" && continue
   count=$(($count + 1))
   #printf '%s\n' "$count: $file"
done < <(printf '%s\000' *)
echo "$count"
```